# Is the set of continuous functions from $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ closed in the same set from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be the set of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{C}$, equipped with the norm $\|f\| = \int\limits_0^1 |f(x)|dx$, and let $S$ be the subspace of those functions into $\mathbb{R}$.  I know that neither $X$ nor $S$ is complete with respect to this norm.  But is $S$ closed in $X$?  My guess would be yes, but how would I go about proving that I can put a little open ball around a function $g$ which takes a value in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: So, if some values of $g$ are non-real, how about using the radius $\|\mathrm{Im}(g)\|$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show the complement is open. Show that the nearest element of $X$ to $f$ is $\mathrm{Re}\,f$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\psi:\>X\to{\mathbb R}$ defined by
$$\psi(f):=\int_0^1\left|{\rm Im}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\right|\>dx$$
is  continuous on $X$:
$$|\psi(f)-\psi(g)|\leq\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|\>dx=\|f-g\|\ .$$
Therefore $S:=\psi^{-1}(0)$ is closed in $X$.